# Two Finger Tap On Glass Live Card

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

How do I capture a two finger tap on a live card. I know I can open a menu with setAction, but I would like to capture more than that.

Currently:

```
public class MyApp extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    MainServer.singleton(this).updateStatus(MainServer.ONLINE);
    if (mLiveCard == null) {
        mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this, LIVE_CARD_TAG);
        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, LiveCardMenuActivity.class);
        mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, menuIntent, 0));
        ....
    }
}
...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy or even advisable way to do this. The RemoteViews object in a typical Service implementation cannot register a touch gesture listener.

Comment: Thank you. Knowing it isn't possible is also worthwhile, so I don't waste time.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `GestureDetector` as a private, global variable, then initialize it in your `onCreate()` method, catching the gesture `Gesture.TWO_TAP`. This is what that looks like:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createGestureDetector(this);
    }


    private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
        gestureDetector.setBaseListener( new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
                if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_TAP) {
                    // do whatever you want on tap with two fingers
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return gestureDetector;
    }

    /*
     * Send generic motion events to the gesture detector
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mGestureDetector != null) {
            return mGestureDetector.onMotionEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's that simple! You can read more about `GestureDetector`s on Google Glass [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch).

Comment: Not sure, this would work on an activity, but what about a live card. I added my code, I thought it was standard code for a live card so I originally didn't add anything, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: @msj121 you're right, I think I may have read this too quickly. My bad.

Comment: No problem. Still not sure how, or rather whether it is possible.